# Build Xml document from SQL Query using For Xml clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xsd, schema

I'm using AdventureWorks Database and I'd like to build xml block using query with FOR XML clause 
but i need to specify specific XML Schema in the result to have its datatypes and so on..

e.g. this sample query " copied "

```
 SELECT e.EmployeeID, c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName
 FROM HumanResources.Employee e INNER JOIN Person.Contact c
 ON c.ContactID = e.ContactID
 WHERE c.FirstName = 'Rob'
 FOR XML RAW ('Employee'), ROOT ('Employees'), ELEMENTS XSINIL, XMLSCHEMA;
```

gets this result

```
<Employees xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />

    <xsd:element name="Employee">

      <xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:sequence>

          <xsd:element name="EmployeeID" type="sqltypes:int" nillable="1" />

          <xsd:element name="FirstName" nillable="1">

            <xsd:simpleType sqltypes:sqlTypeAlias="[AdventureWorks].[dbo].[Name]">

              <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">

                <xsd:maxLength value="50" />

              </xsd:restriction>

            </xsd:simpleType>

          </xsd:element>

          <xsd:element name="MiddleName" nillable="1">

            <xsd:simpleType sqltypes:sqlTypeAlias="[AdventureWorks].[dbo].[Name]">

              <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">

                <xsd:maxLength value="50" />

              </xsd:restriction>

            </xsd:simpleType>

          </xsd:element>

          <xsd:element name="LastName" nillable="1">

            <xsd:simpleType sqltypes:sqlTypeAlias="[AdventureWorks].[dbo].[Name]">

              <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">

                <xsd:maxLength value="50" />

              </xsd:restriction>

            </xsd:simpleType>

          </xsd:element>

        </xsd:sequence>

      </xsd:complexType>

    </xsd:element>

  </xsd:schema>

  <Employee xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1">

    <EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>

    <FirstName>Rob</FirstName>

    <MiddleName xsi:nil="true" />

    <LastName>Walters</LastName>

  </Employee>

  <Employee xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1">

    <EmployeeID>168</EmployeeID>

    <FirstName>Rob</FirstName>

    <MiddleName>T</MiddleName>

    <LastName>Caron</LastName>

  </Employee>

</Employees>
```

i need to refer to another online schema .. is that possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need your query to adhere to an existing schema, I think you should take control of the generated XML yourself by using, e.g., [`EXPLICIT` mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068%28v=sql.105%29). You can't use the `XMLSCHEMA` option in this case, but it's OK since you already have your own schema.

Comment: i used AUTO mode but i add namespaces and all prefixes inside the query hard-coded .. its really huge query but i don have another solution, what do u mean by using `EXPLICIT` mode, i was looking for a way to add the exist `xml schema` coz i donno how to add it actually within the query, i used `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` clause but its still poor result

Comment: The idea is that you'd use `EXPLICIT` mode and create the XML that conforms to your XSD _by hand_. In that case, you don't need the query to know about your XSD.